# prism mef ViewSortHint not working

Tags: wpf, prism, mef

Please help. I use Prism wpf + mef 6.1.0

Registered all views for each region through attribute

```
   [ViewExport(RegionName = RegionNames.NavigatorRegion)]
   [PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.Shared)]
   [ViewSortHint("1")]
   public partial class AView: UserControl
   {
   }

   [ViewExport(RegionName = RegionNames.NavigatorRegion)]
   [PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.Shared)]
   [ViewSortHint("2")]
   public partial class BView: UserControl
   {
   }
```

And show them in shell using ContentControl

```
 <ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static r:RegionNames.NavigatorRegion}"/>
```

I use ContentControl because i need only one active view. However BView always display first but i set for it  [ViewSortHint("2")].

What wrong? When i remove BView then AView display first correct.

Comment: can you give us more informations about what you want ?

Comment: I want when shell loaded AView displayed.

Answer (score 1):

`ViewSortHintAttribute` only has a meaning if your region supports displaying multiple views at the same time, like an `ItemsControl` or a `TabControl`.

If you want to use a simple `ContentControl` (which can only display a single view), then you have to use either navigation or view injection.

How to inject a view, you can read [on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921076(v=pandp.20).aspx):

1. Obtain a reference to the `IRegionManager` via dependency injection.
2. Obtain the region where you want to place your view.

e.g.:

```
IRegion mainRegion = regionManager.Regions[RegionNames.NavigatorRegion];
```

3. Add the view to the region (optionally removing a previously added view).

---

Alternativelly, you can use view based navigation. Take a look on this [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg430861(v=pandp.40).aspx).

```
// Obtain region manager via DI
IRegionManager regionManager = ...;
regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.NavigatorRegion, new Uri("ViewA", UriKind.Relative));
```